# Changing 3D coordinate system using Excel

Tags: excel, 3d, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation

I have a cloud of points in my spreadsheet in a certain coordinate system the cloud is in this format:

`Name X  Y  Z
PT1  X1 Y1 Z1
PT2  X2 Y2 Z2
PT3  X3 Y3 Z3
PT4  X4 Y4 Z4
...
PTi  Xi Yi Zi
...`

I want to use four first points in my list to construct a new coordinate frame and transpose all my points in the new frame.

The new coordinate frame has to be defined as a plane-line-point (or a 3-2-1° transformation as such:

1. Plane is the best fit plane of (PT1, PT2, PT3, PT4). I know how to construct a plane equation using the excel LINEST formula
2. Line / vector Midpoint(PT1-PT2) to Midpoint(PT3-PT4) line / vector is easy to construct in excel
3. Point is Midpoint(PT1-PT2).

To summarize the origin (0,0,0) would be at the Midpoint(PT1-PT2). The new X axis would be the vector Midpoint(PT1-PT2) to Midpoint(PT3-PT4). The Y axis would be contained in the plane and perpendicular to X. And Z would be perpendicular to X and Y.

Currently I'm able to find the equations of the Plane, and X, Y, Z axis.

My question is how to construct the transformation matrix based on these parameters and implement it using excel formulas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Command needed in J6 to L16 below via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to reset coords to original values

=RotpointsZ(RotpointsY(RotpointsX(AsArray($F$6:$H$16),$K$1),$K$2),$K$3)

How can I edit the VBA code to read a different xyz rotation for every rotated row instead of being tied to one rotation as displayed here?

26/04/18 WORF on Mr.Excel just answered my question of reading a different xyz rotation for each point to be rotated. His input was to add the following code to the existing code:

```
Function Rot3D(ByVal rng1 As Range, ByVal rng2 As Range, ByVal rng3 As 
Range, ByVal rng4 As Range)
Rot3D = RotPointsX(RotPointsY(RotPointsZ(AsArray(rng1), rng2.Value), 
rng3.Value), rng4.Value)
End Function
```

Copy the following formula:

```
=rot3d(b2:d2,h2,g2,f2)
```

into cells J2,K2,L2 using ctrl+shift+enter and then copy down. The rotation of the xyz coordinates in columns B,C,D, will be rotated as per the angles in columns F,G,H, with output in columns J,K,L

I have placed the rotation angles in columns F,G,H, using cut and paste. This of course changes the layout of the original sheet which is displayed here.

Answer (score 1):

I try to answer dividing the task into 5 parts. I will call x,y,z the old axis centered in O and X,Y,Z your new axis centered in P.

**Try to save you partial result in empty cells for the first try. I can't give you a single unique formula that answer your question in 1 step.**

a) A generic transformation is a rototranslation. You found your new origin in point P (you have the coordinates). Assuming that your "old origin" is O = (0,0,0), I can simply say that the translation from the old origin to the new origin is d = |P-O| = |P| euclidean norm of vector P in both systems and it's quite easy to calculate in excel (I don't know if there is a function, I would use use Pythagoras theorem). Someone try to build a user defined macro [here](https://superuser.com/questions/929693/euclidean-distance-between-two-points-with-coordinates-stored-as-strings)

b) Now that you have the translation vector (t1,t2,t3), your are able to set a new origin for the old axis, without rotating them. Pay attention to the sign, but is a simple translation formula (see the example: 
if x = x' + t1  then x' = x - t1) Think which is x' and which is x in your case, try with a simple point (1,0,0) and watch if your choice is good.
Do the translation of all you points (i.e: PT1_t, PT2_t...)
Now you have a mid-reference system between xyz e XYZ. Let's call it "pqr"

c) Now your reference systems pqr and XYZ differ only in rotation angle. You have to decide which axis will rotate first before build the rotation matrix. 
It is better to work with normalized vector (divide each vector for its norm)
Let's say that the rotation from the pqr system and the XYZ is the composition of (at most) 3 rotation around a fixed axis. 
For example

1. you will rotate pqr around Z to put versor p in XZ plane. you will obtain a "new" pqr' system. This is done with a 3x3 rotation matrix RX (we don't know it yet)
2. you will rotate pqr' around Y to align versor p' to versor X using RY. You now have pqr''
3. you will align q axis to Y and r axis to Z using a rotation around X and a matrix RX. pqr''' is completely aligned to XYZ

The total rotation is R = RX * RY * RZ, a matrix product. How to find the rotation? (Following my sequence of rotation is not mandatory! You can build your own sequence, but XYZ, ZYX and ZXZ are the most famous).

d) Every matrix needs an angle. The first angle is the angle between p and its' projection in XZ plane. The second angle is the angle between p' ( = RZ * p) and X, the third angle is between q'' ( = RY * q' = RY * RX * q) and Y. It must be equal (with errors) to the angle between r'' and Z. 
Matrix can be build like that (if A is a generic angle)

```
RX = [1   0      0
      0 cos(A) -sin(A)
      0 sin(A) cos(A)]
```

check RY and RZ [at this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations) but pay attention: as we said before A is the angle of rotation in one direction, so you may need -A for your rotation. In general (but verify it) A is the angle FROM the old axis TO the new one, and positive A is counterclockwise.

To calculate angle A use the simple formula [exposed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463415/angle-between-two-3d-lines). Excel has all the goniometric formulas (cosine, arccosine...) that you need.

e) Once you have found the three matrices RX RY RZ playing with the rotation of the old pqr axis, every single point PTi' in your new XYZ system is obtained from PTi' = R * PTi_t.
You can simply build the matrix product with the MMULT excel function 
[explained here](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Mmult-Function.html)

Sorry for the lenght, but is the only system I know as a simple student.
I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code that allows rotations on a range of points arranged by rows.

[image: scr]

First the three functions that take an array of values and apply corresponding rotations about X, Y or Z.

```
Public Function RotPointsX(ByRef pts() As Variant, angle_rad As Double) As Variant()
    Dim n As Integer
    n = UBound(pts, 1)
    If UBound(pts, 2) <> 3 Then
        'Need Three Points
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim tX As Double, tY As Double, tZ As Double
    Dim X As Double, Y As Double, Z As Double

    For i = 1 To n
        tX = pts(i, 1): tY = pts(i, 2): tZ = pts(i, 3)
        X = tX
        Y = tY * Cos(angle_rad) - tZ * Sin(angle_rad)
        Z = tY * Sin(angle_rad) + tZ * Cos(angle_rad)
        pts(i, 1) = X: pts(i, 2) = Y: pts(i, 3) = Z
    Next i

    RotPointsX = pts
End Function
Public Function RotPointsY(ByRef pts() As Variant, angle_rad As Double) As Variant()
    Dim n As Integer
    n = UBound(pts, 1)
    If UBound(pts, 2) <> 3 Then
        'Need Three Points
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim tX As Double, tY As Double, tZ As Double
    Dim X As Double, Y As Double, Z As Double

    For i = 1 To n
        tX = pts(i, 1): tY = pts(i, 2): tZ = pts(i, 3)
        X = tZ * Sin(angle_rad) + tX * Cos(angle_rad)
        Y = tY
        Z = tZ * Cos(angle_rad) - tX * Sin(angle_rad)
        pts(i, 1) = X: pts(i, 2) = Y: pts(i, 3) = Z
    Next i

    RotPointsY = pts
End Function
Public Function RotPointsZ(ByRef pts() As Variant, angle_rad As Double) As Variant()
    Dim n As Integer
    n = UBound(pts, 1)
    If UBound(pts, 2) <> 3 Then
        'Need Three Points
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim tX As Double, tY As Double, tZ As Double
    Dim X As Double, Y As Double, Z As Double

    For i = 1 To n
        tX = pts(i, 1): tY = pts(i, 2): tZ = pts(i, 3)
        X = tX * Cos(angle_rad) - tY * Sin(angle_rad)
        Y = tX * Sin(angle_rad) + tY * Cos(angle_rad)
        Z = tZ
        pts(i, 1) = X: pts(i, 2) = Y: pts(i, 3) = Z
    Next i

    RotPointsZ = pts
End Function
```

Next I need a function to convert a range into an array, and the easiest way to do this with this function:

```
Public Function AsArray(ByVal r_pts As Range) As Variant()
    AsArray = r_pts.Value2
End Function
```

Finally in my sheet I do the rotations as nested functions and entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> as array funtions

[image: scr]

So for an Euler rotation of `ZYX` the following enter is needed

```
=RotPointsX(
     RotPointsY(
         RotPointsZ(
             AsArray(<range>),
         angle_z),
     angle_y), 
 angle_x)
```

The inverse rotation is a `XYZ` rotation of negative angles

```
=RotPointsZ(
     RotPointsY(
         RotPointsX(
             AsArray(<range>),
         -angle_x),
     -angle_y), 
 -angle_z)
```

I have verifies this by restoring the original points

[image: scr]